# Can an Azure Search query using Lucene query syntax have a filter with a geo.distance function AND another filter criteria?

Tags: odata, geospatial, azure-cognitive-search

I'm querying an Azure Search index containing train schedule stops using Lucene syntax with a filter using the geo.distance function and a departure time value (expressed as minutes from midnight.  The query works when I have either the geo.distance function alone in the filter, or the departure time as the only filter, but having both present with AND (or &&) returns an invalid expression syntax error.

{
    "search":"stationName:Naperville",
    "queryType":"full",
    "filter":"geo.distance(location, geography'POINT(-88.145118 41.775038)') le 1.0 AND departureTimeInMinutes ge 1400"
}

The error message for the above query is:
{
    "error": {
        "code": "",
        "message": "Invalid expression: Syntax error at position 73 in 'geo.distance(location, geography'POINT(-88.145118 41.775038)') le 1.0 AND departureTimeInMinutes ge 1400'.\r\nParameter name: $filter"
    }
}

Any help is hugely appreciated! Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

I apologize for posting and answering my own question - but I just learned that the OData expression syntax for Azure Search is very much *case-sensitive*. My query with a lower-case "and" works.

The following version of the query in my question is successful:
{
    "search":"stationName:Naperville",
    "queryType":"full",
    "filter":"geo.distance(location, geography'POINT(-88.145118 41.775038)') le 1.0 and departureTimeInMinutes ge 1400"
}

Comment: Glad you found the solution! This case is especially tricky, because the full Lucene syntax is case-sensitive too, and the syntax of the logical operators in that case is all-caps. So it's AND/OR in Lucene queries, and/or in OData filters.